# How to parse XML without a schema?

Tags: c#, xml

I recieve this piece of xml:

```
<hash>
  <base>XPM</base>
  <alt>BTC</alt>
  <value type="decimal">0.00341</value>
</hash>
```

How do I get the values of base, alt and value tags? I would also like to know that the type attribute is decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ2XML

```
XElement node=XElement.Parse(input);
node.Element("base").Value;
node.Element("alt").Value;
node.Element("value").Attributes("type").Value;//attribute value
node.Element("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XPath:
Get alt nodes - `//hash/alt`
Get value nodes with type="decimal" - `//hash/value[@type="decimal"]`